# How to handle uneven number of bytes when writing a huffman-encoded string to a file in Java?

Tags: java, encoding, binary, compression, huffman-code

So I'm attempting to create an adaptive Huffman encoding algorithm and I've run into a bit of a roadblock that I'm not sure how to resolve.

My algorithm works completely as intended, except for with one minor issue; I can't seem to figure out how to ensure extra characters aren't written when the compression result doesn't have exactly 8 bits for every byte.

As an example; here's the ending fragment of my input text

```
subscribe to our email newsletter to hear about new eBooks.

fa
```

and here's the ending fragment of the same text after being encoded then decoded

```
subscribe to our email newsletter to hear about new eBooks.

fa
as
```

The extra "as" characters are a result of the final compression bits not being part of a full byte; the last byte is represented by the bits "0111", which are internally recognized as "00000111" by the program, which cause the last two characters to be written. Beyond that, when I tried to apply padding to the end of this byte, causing it to be seen as "01110000", the ending fragment appeared as follows.

```
subscribe to our email newsletter to hear about new eBooks.

fa
r
```

This is marginally better, but the extra "r" character is written as the code for "r" with this encoding is "0000", causing this complication.

How would I avoid this?

If it means anything, to get the bits, I'm  manipulating an encoded String containing a sequence of 1s and 0s with the following chunk of code.

split is a string array where the strings are split into 8 characters, and list is an ArrayList containing a list of integers stored to later be output into a string of binary representations.

```
String[] split = frankenstein.encodedString.split("(?<=\\G.{8})");
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {

    String str = split[i];
                
    //Adds 0 padding at the end of the bits if it's necessary
    if (i == split.length - 1) {
        if (str.length() != 8) {
            for (int j = str.length(); j < 8 ;j++) 
                str += "0";
        }          
    }

list.add(Integer.parseInt(str, 2));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either a) send the number of characters to decode ahead of the encoded message, or b) include a unique end-of-stream symbol as the last symbol in what you are coding. An example for the latter would be if you are encoding bytes in the range 0..255, add a symbol at the end with value 256, that cannot appear in the preceding data.